# How to iterate string and number mixed enum in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
enum MixedEnum {
  A = 1,
  B = 'b',
  C = 'B',
  D = '2'
}
```

The above code is a string and number mixed enum. I want to iterate the value of `MixedEnum`. For example, `[1, 'b', 'B', '2']` or keys `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`. It there has a simple way to do?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a mixed enum??  I didn't know that was even allowed!

As you probably know, number-valued enum members have both their key and their value saved on the `MixedEnum` object, while string-valued members have only their key saved.  So you can iterate the keys by filtering out numeric-named members of `MixedEnum`.  We can get a hint about the precise way to do the filtering from the [TypeScript checker](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/4ac8976750dcaf3caa5d6424d2ea00eb916feafe/src/compiler/checker.ts)'s check that disallows numeric-named members:

```
if (isNumericLiteralName(text) && !isInfinityOrNaNString(text)) {
    error(member.name, Diagnostics.An_enum_member_cannot_have_a_numeric_name);
}
```

where:

```
function isNumericLiteralName(name: string | __String) {
    // [comments omitted]
    return (+name).toString() === name;
}
```

So the iteration code would be:

```
for (let item in MixedEnum) { 
  if ((+item).toString() === item && 0 * (+item) === 0) continue;
  // item is a key, MixedEnum[item] is its value; process
}
```